# Ways to use electromagnets to pick up metal shavings at a distance

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics

I work at a rotor machining plant and there is an issue for shutting a line down to clean up metal shavings, causes too much down time. I was thinking of using a strong electromagnet to have a "pick up" radius under the machining cells, say 12". After thinking about creating my own and a failed prototype and also looking online to buy one I am not seeing any that have a effective radius. Is it even possible to achieve what I am trying to do? Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: If your equipment is made out of ferromagnetic materials (steel) the magnetic field lines will tend to concentrate within them, attracting shavings to all kinds of angles and potrusions within the machinery.

Comment: Good point, didn't think of that

Comment: Are you actually machining _ferrous_ material?

Comment: Yes, cast rotors. So cast iron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pick up shavings 12" from the magnet, that's probably not going to work, even with absurdly strong magnets. If it did work, what would you do with them THEN?

I'm having a hard time visualizing exactly what your setup looks like, but something that moved a magnet around the area so it was closer to the chips (and then moved it over a hopper, bin, or belt and turned off the magnet) might be more effective. Then again, ignoring the "magnet" aspect completely and mechanically sweeping, or vacuuming (as in a large air-transport chip collector, not a shop vac) might work (will depend somewhat on the nature of the chips - long, stringy, curly, sharp ones are much harder to handle than short chips.)

If you have issues with build-up IN the machines, you may need to arrange air-blast or something to get them to the floor or collection system. Depending on what exactly the constraints are, something like a wide belt under each machine section that either dumps the chips where they can be safely collected as operations continue, or onto another belt that takes them away might work.

Comment: Isn't the point of an electromagnet to turn on and off? reverse polarity or what ever? Mechanical system wouldn't work, operators and change over techs have to walk around inside the line cage, everywhere within the cage. I guess the magnet idea is a bust. Thanks for the info. The prototype I made was six 2" coils on a iron shaft facing each other. N to N and S to S with 2" spacers between each coil, This way I could achieve sections of 2" with a magnet field between them. It works for about 1/2" perpendicular from the bar but the iron heats up. I think I made an inductor.

Comment: Yes, one point of an electromagnet is that it turns off - but it' still not clear from here how your idea (if workable) would deal with the chips once stuck to the magnet. The iron heats up due to eddy currents (which can be solved with a laminated or ferrite core), and you'd do a lot better with each coil acting separately (cut 3"-4" slugs, attach pole pieces (additional steel or iron parts) to each end to make a rough U, array the 6 of them to point the 12 poles where you want things picked up.)

Comment: @Duraholiday: "_Isn't the point of an electromagnet to turn on and off? **reverse polarity or what ever?**_" Just to be clear, reversing the polarity won't repel the material - it's still an electromagnet.

Comment: Well I was planning that gravity would come into affect once the electromagnet was shut off and the shavings would fall into a trough below.

Comment: I would just use a (bigger) trough and skip the electromagnet idea. It might work well on a broom, but any significant magnetic field strength at 12" distance would require a lot of power. A LOT. Too much to be practical.

Answer (score 0):

[oooooooooo]

[oooooooooo]

[oooooooooo]

^^^^^^^^^^^^ Pictured above is a idea, I was wondering if it would work. The plan would be to have an array or bar of magnets. The shavings could move from bar to bar as each magnetic bar was powered. To my understanding this would operate on a similar principal as a coil gun? Is this a possible set up?